# Flag dialog is under sidebar text

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, flag-dialog, left-nav

The flag dialog is under the left sidebar text. This only started happening over the past day or two.
Using Safari 12.1.1 on MacOS High Sierra.
Successfully reproduced on StackOverflow and PPCG, along with their respective metas.

[image]

(EDIT: [It happens here (SE Meta) as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjdpc.png))

Comment: Happens in Chrome, too, also on a Mac. Also impacts the Close dialogue and mod dialogue but not the comment flagging dialogue.

Comment: the dialog has a z-index of 2000, the sidebar has a z-index of 5000. IIRC the z-index used to be 1000 so it already must have had prior competition that it is now 2000.... not sure how big you can make that number....

Comment: @rene https://stackoverflow.com/a/25461690/8828658 -- 2^31 - 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is building now.

There was a change to z-index in Stacks which bumped the leftnav up to 5000.  The thing is, though, leftnav didn't need a z-index.  When it's inline with the page, it can just have its natural z-index, and when it's living in the top nav, it gets the standard z-index for a top nav dialog.  This was probably left-over from a previous implementation.